# How to avoid "ssh localhost" password in MacOS?

Tags: macos, hadoop, ssh, configuration, localhost

I am configuring a local Hadoop cluster but I have a problem with password configurations.

When I type

```
ssh localhost
```

This message is displayed:

```
ssh localhost
key_load_public: invalid format
```

I already tried using these commands to replace my previous authorized keys:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] or [su]. When you do, you should run `ls -la` on your `.ssh` directory and include the output in your question. Also include the relevant lines from your .ssh/config file, if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.config` file in your `~/.ssh` directory and then add the credentials.

Like this,

```
// ~/.ssh/config
# SSH Host configuration file

# Default for all
Host *
  ForwardAgent no
  ForwardX11 yes
  ForwardX11Trusted yes

Host <hostname_here>
  HostName <ip_address>
  User <user_name>
```

Since it seems that your problems is more related with keys, you can try using `ssh -i <your key file> username@ip_addr -p <port>`